# Minimize $\mbox{tr}(AX)$ where $X$ is an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

Let $A, X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. The scalar objective function is
$$J=\mathrm{tr}(AX)$$
If no constraints, let the derivative of $J$ with respect to $X$ be zeros, then we have
$$A=0$$
Suppose $A$ is also a complex function, from $A=0$ I can further calculate something.

**My question is**: what if $X$ is an orthogonal matrix, i.e., $X^TX=I$? Then it becomes an constrained optimization problem. Can I still use matrix differential techniques to derive the minimizer? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method of [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) yields the solution.

One studies the (real-valued) function $F(X)$ with the (matrix) constraint that $C(X)=I$ for $F(X)=\text{trace}(AX)$ and $C(X)=X^TX$, hence 
$$
F(X)=\sum\limits_{ij}A_{ji}X_{ij},\quad
C_{ij}(X)=\sum\limits_{k}X_{ki}X_{kj}.
$$
The gradients of $F$ and $C$ are given by $\partial_{ij}F(X)=A_{ji}$ and $$
\partial_{ij}C_{k\ell}(X)=X_{i\ell}[k=j]+X_{ik}[\ell=j].
$$
One wants that there exists some *multipliers* $\lambda_{ij}$ such that, for every $i$ and $j$, 
$$
\partial_{ij}F(X)=\sum\limits_{k\ell}\lambda_{k\ell}\partial_{ij}C_{k\ell}(X).
$$
This condition reads
$$
A_{ji}=\sum\limits_{k,\ell}\lambda_{k\ell}\left(X_{i\ell}[k=j]+X_{ik}[\ell=j]\right)=\sum\limits_{\ell}\lambda_{j\ell}X_{i\ell}+\sum\limits_{k}\lambda_{kj}X_{ik},
$$
or, equivalently, introducing the matrix  $\Lambda=(\lambda_{ij})$,
$$
A^T=X\Lambda^T+X\Lambda.
$$
The matrix $M=\Lambda^T+\Lambda$ is such that $M^T=M$ and $XM=A^T$, hence $X^TX=I$ implies that $M$ should be such that $M^TM=M^2=AA^T$.

<strike>Using [pseudo-inverse matrices](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-inverse) if $A$ is not invertible and the usual definition of the square root of a symmetric matrix, one sees that the maximizing and minimizing matrices $X$ and the maximum and minimum values of $F$ are</strike>

When $A$ is invertible, one can use the usual definition of the square root of a symmetric matrix to find $M$. The maximizing and minimizing matrices $X$ and the maximum and minimum values of $F$ are$$
X_0=A^TM^{-1}=\pm A^T(AA^T)^{-1/2},\quad
F(X_0)=\pm\mbox{trace}((AA^T)^{1/2}).
$$
When $A$ is not invertible, the formula $X_0=A^TM^{-1}$, whichever meaning one gives to the notation $M^{-1}$, cannot yield an orthogonal matrix $X_0$ since, if $A$ is not invertible, neither are $A^T$, nor $A^T$ times any matrix. On the other hand, the formula $F(X_0)=\pm\mbox{trace}((AA^T)^{1/2})$ might still be valid.

Comment: Nice Solution! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Didier -- I need this solution for the answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225276), but I don't understand the part about the pseudoinverses. In that case, $AA^T$ (in your notation, not the $A$ from the other question) may not be invertible; e.g. for one example I have

$$A=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}\;,$$

and it seems that in that case I can't get $X_0$ in the way you've written it, even using the pseudoinverse, because the resulting matrix isn't orthogonal?

Comment: I found another solution and used it in the answer but also linked to this question here; I'd be interested to know if what you had in mind with the pseudoinverse is equivalent to the singular-value decomposition used there.

Comment: @joriki It has been a long time since I wrote this... It seems that here $AA^T$ is symmetric nonnegative hence diagonalizable as $AA^T=PDP^T$ with $PP^T=I$ and $D$ a diagonal matrix with a diagonal $(d_k)_k$, $d_k\geqslant0$. Then $(AA^T)^{-1/2}=PFP^T$ where $F$ is the diagonal matrix with the diagonal $(f_k)_k$, $f_k=1/\sqrt{d_k}$ if $d_k\gt0$, $f_k=0$ if $d_k=0$. But maybe this was not your question?

Comment: @did: Thanks. My question was: For $A$ as in my example above, we have

$$
AA^T=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}\;,
$$

so your prescription gives

$$
(AA^T)^{-1/2}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}\;,
$$

so we get

$$X_0=\pm\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}\;,$$

which isn't orthogonal.

Comment: @joriki Anyway, $X_0=\pm A^T\cdot$anything cannot be orthogonal when $A$ is not invertible, hence this case of the proof does not hold. Hmmmm... :-(

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. In the meantime an answer has been added that derives the solution I'd found for the answer to the other question.

Comment: @Did and joriki: The polar decomposition theorem for $A$ basically states that you can always  factorize $A =RU$ where $U$ is the square root of $A^TA$ and $R$ is orthogonal. If I remember right, the invertibility of $A$ gives you unique orthogonal $R$. Thus, in the given problem what it means is that the extremizer $Q$ is not unique, but the value of the extremum is the same.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to get did's answer is to use the [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) to reduce to the case of $A$ being diagonal: We have $A = USV'$, where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal and $S$ is diagonal, and so

$$\def\Tr{\operatorname{Tr}}\Tr(AX) = \Tr(SV'XU)\;.$$

Since $X\to V'XU$ is a bijection on the set of orthogonal matrices,

$$\min\{\Tr(AX)\mid X\text{ orthogonal}\} = \min\{\Tr(SW)\mid W\text{ orthogonal}\}\;.$$

But $\Tr(SW) = \sum_iS_{ii}W_{ii}$, and all the $S_{ii}$ are non-negative and $-1\le W_{ii}\le1$, so that $\Tr(SW)\ge\Tr(S(-I))$, and so the minimum occurs at $W=-I$ (or $X=-VU'$) and is $-\sum_iS_{ii}$.

Comment: I formatted your answer because I thought it's important to have this solution worked out here; but it was quite a bit of work; I encourage you to take a look at the [formatting FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference); it's not as hard as it might seem.