# How to solve an overdetermined system of point mappings via rotation and translation

Tags: transformation, rotations, coordinate-systems, problem-solving

I have a set of points in one coordinate system $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ and their corresponding points in another coordinate system $Q_1, \ldots , Q_n$. All points are in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I'm looking for a "best fit" transformation consisting of a rotation and a translation.
I.e.

$$ \min_{A,b} \sum (A p_i + b - q_i)^2 , \quad A \in \operatorname{SO}(3), b \in \mathbb{R}^3$$

Can anyone give me some hint in which direction I should search?

I already looked at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares  (don't know how to include the restriction to orthogonal matrices)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition  (I thought that I'd start with a matrix from $\operatorname{GL}(3)$ and use the "best fit orthogonal matrix" afterwards like stated in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem but that seamed too complicated)

Comment: Note that the stationarity condition with respect to $b$ can be solved explicitly: Differentiating with respect to $b$ yields $\sum(Ap_i+b-q_i)=0$ and thus $b=q-Ap$ with $p$ and $q$ the centroids of the $p_i$ and $q_i$, respectively, so you can subtract out the centroids and then you only need to minimize $\sum(A(p_i-p)-(q_i-q))^2$ with respect to the rotation.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the Mathjax. I didn't see the result in my edit since our virus scanner blocked the mathJax script ;-). I hope  it'll improve in future posts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in my comment, first subtract out the centroids to reduce the problem to

$$
\min_A\sum_i\|Ap_i-q_i\|^2\;,\quad A\in SO(3)\;.
$$

That problem is solved [here](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/talks/procrust94.ps.gz) (page 9), with the vectors $p_i$ and $q_i$ assembled into the matrices $B$ and $A$ (with the present $A$ corresponding to $Q$), but I'll write it out with the vectors in your notation.

The problem appears to be quadratic in $A$, but it isn't, since

$$
\begin{align}
\|Ap_i-q_i\|^2&=(Ap_i-q_i)^\top(Ap_i-q_i)
\\
&=p_iA^\top Ap_i+q_i^\top q_i-2q_i^\top Ap_i
\\
&=
p_ip_i+q_i^\top q_i-2q_i^\top Ap_i\;,
\end{align}
$$

since $A$ is orthogonal. Thus all we need to do is maximize

$$
\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}
\sum_iq_i^\top Ap_i=\sum_i\tr q_i^\top Ap_i=\sum_i\tr p_iq_i^\top A=\tr\left(\left(\sum_ip_iq_i^\top\right)A\right)=:\tr B^\top A
$$

subject to the constraint $A\in SO(3)$. That problem is solved in the document linked to above, using the [singular-value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) $B=U\Sigma V^\top$. For $A\in O(3)$ the solution is $A=UV^\top$, whereas if $A$ is restricted to $SO(3)$, the solution is $A=UZV^\top$, where $Z$ is the identity matrix, but with the last diagonal element replaced by $-1$ if this is required to make $\det A$ positive.

See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65231) [which in the meantime has received [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/225509) that derives the above solution to $\tr B^\top A\to\min$ for the case $A\in O(n)$].

Comment: Since you use the trace I assume I have to use the Frobenius norm to follow your steps. Since I'd like to measure the transformation error for a given set of points according to the 2-norm, will this work?

Comment: @Onur: I don't understand the question. How is the fact that the solution uses the trace related to the measure of the transformation error? I started from your definition of your error and derived how to minimize it; where do you see a potential for problems?

Comment: I mixed up two different things: transformation error and error induced due to the "erroneous" transformation.

Answer (score 2):

I try to summarize what I have to do in this answer:

1. Convert the $P_i$s and $Q_i$s:

   $\overline{p}$ and $\overline{q}$ are the center of gravity for the set of points to be mapped:
   $$ \overline{p} := \frac1i\sum_iP_i, \quad \overline{q} := \frac1i\sum_iQ_i$$
   Make the points relative to their respective center of gravity:
   $$ p_i := P_i - \overline{p}, \quad q_i := Q_i - \overline{q}$$
   This removes the need to consider the translation $b$ in the optimization. $b$ can be calculated as $\overline{q} - A \overline{p}$ once we have determined the optimal $A$.
2. Calulate $B$ as
   $$B = \left(\sum_i p q^\top \right)^\top = \sum_i q p ^\top$$
3. Perform SVD decomposition of $B$:
   $$ B = U \Sigma V^\top$$
4. Optimal $A$ if $A \in \operatorname{O}(3)$ (not $A \in \operatorname{SO}(3)$ as stated in the question):
   $$ A := U V^\top $$
   Optimal $b$:
   $$ b := \overline{q} - A \overline{p}$$
5. Optimal $A$ if $A \in \operatorname{SO}(3)$ would go here but I think $A \in \operatorname{O}(3)$ is what I'm really looking for.

Comment: Looks good to me.